# Handling the distinction between undefined- and null-parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know very well that null and undefined are distinct in JavaScript. However, I can't seem to decide whether or not use that fact when my own functions are passed one of those as its argument.

Or, expressed in a different way, should `myFoo(undefined)` return the same thing as `myFoo(null)`?

Or, in yet another case, since `myBar(1, 2, 3)` is (almost) the same thing as `myBar(1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined)`, should `myBar(1, 2, 3, null, null)` return the same thing as `myBar(1, 2, 3)`?

I feel that there's potential for confusion in both cases and that a library should probably follow a convention when handling null/undefined.

I'm not really asking for personal opinions (so please express those as comments rather than answers). I'm asking if anyone knows if there is a best practice that one should stick to when it comes to handling this distinction. References to external sources are very welcome!

Comment: `myBar(1, 2, 3)` is not the same thing as `myBar(1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined)`: the `arguments` object will have length of 3 in the first case and 5 in the second.

Comment: Ah, good point. Then I suppose its only the same thing if I explicitly receive five parameters and use them while ignoring the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say that while, most of the time, there is little value in distinguishing between the two, the cases where there *is* value tend to be quite interesting.

Take, for example, a function which can be given a callback.  `undefined` might indicate that some default callback should be used (as if the parameter weren't specified), but `null` could indicate that no callback should be made at all:

```
function asyncWorker(data, callback, timeout) {
    if (typeof callback === "undefined") {
        callback = function() { $("#log").append("<p>Done!</p>"); };
    }

    // ...

    if (callback) callback();
}

asyncWorker([1, 2, 3]); // default callback, no timeout
asyncWorker([4, 5, 6], null); // no callback, no timeout
asyncWorker([7, 8, 9], undefined, 10000); // default callback, 10s timeout
```

Of course, `false` or `0` could be used instead of `null` here, but that might not be the case in a more complex example.  And whether your code benefits from the additional parameter complexity is entirely up to you.  :-)

Comment: Using one of the special values as "nothing" and one as "default" sure is interesting. Great example! Is this concept common in JavaScript libraries? (I'm only used to jQuery, and even that I've not used very much).

Comment: I've not seen it widely used, but a few hours after writing this answer, I had occasion to distinguish between `null` and `undefined` myself in exactly this manner for an event library I'm writing at work which supports jQuery-style optional parameters (e.g. `method(parm1[, parm2], parm3)`.

Comment: Since when did optional arguments become 'jQuery-style'? =)

Comment: @Sean — When "jQuery-style" was made a project requirement.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Best practice for handling arguments**

- define the expected arguments, what they will be used for, and the types of these
- decide *how* they are accessed, either via the **formal** arguments, or through the `arguments` collection
- define whether values outside the expected range should result in default values
- verify that the arguments are within range before processing
- for boolean values, decide whether they must be true booleans, or only *truthy/falsy*

Step 2, 3 and 4 is of most importance to you in this case

**How to access the arguments**
This is something you will need to select based on *what* the method does, and your strategy for handling a variable amount of arguments.

Take this for example

```
function foo() {
    var args = arguments.length == 1 ? 
        [document.body].concat([arguments[0]]) : 
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    args[0].style.backgroundColor = args[1];
}

foo(document.body, "red");
foo("blue");​
```

**True boolean or truthy/falsy**
How to test for values depends largely on how your code is set up

```
function foo(elem, color) {
    if (!color) { // the correct test here should be 'typeof color == "undefined"'
        color = "green";
    }
    elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

foo(document.body, "red"); //set the background color to red
foo(document.body); //set the background color to the default green
foo(document.body, "");​ //remove the background color !This will fail!
```

The last statement will wrongly use the default value instead of the provided, even though the provided is within the expected range.

When it comes to handling `undefined` values remember that there is no difference in `foo(undefined);` and `foo();` **except** that the length of the `arguments` collection will be different. How this is handled (and if it needs to be) is dependent on how you access the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Its entirely up to you how you handle arguments passed to your function, so its up to you.
If you want to check if an argument is `null` you use

```
if (myVar === null) {
```

and if you want to check if an argument is `undefined` you use

```
if (typeof myVar === "undefined") {
```

If the expected argument is anything other than 0, null or undefined, then you can check for this using

```
if (myVar) {
```

So whether or not your `myFoo(null)` should behave the same as `myFoo(undefined)` is entirely up to how you handle these internally.

When it comes to extra parameters, this has no effect other than the `arguments` collection being larger than expected.

Comment: I *suspect* a comparison with `null` to be (slightly) faster than a comparison with string `"undefined"`.

Comment: @Marcel And your point is? that comparing an apple to an apple is faster than comparing an orange to an orange? Or that the typeof call takes longer time? Of what importance is this?

Comment: From a machine point of view, doing a `typeof` that results in a string and comparing a string with a string is faster than comparing something to `null` (in assembly language most processors have a `JZ` opcode). The OP asked for differences.

Comment: That is of little use here - this piece of 'knowledge' will not help you handle null or undefined values better, which I believe is what he asked for..

Comment: This does not answer the question. As previously stated, I know the difference between the two and that it's up to me to handle it as I desire; it's my program :) What I'm asking is if it's a good idea to handle them differently or not, and why.

Comment: @Jakob: Again, its entirely up to you and strongly depends on the type  of arguments you expect. If your code does not care whether `arg1` is `0`, `undefined` or `null` then just cast it to a boolean, if not then check for the exact value.  The short answer: the best practice is to use the correct method. Would you use `-` to add two numbers` or `*` to divide? Probably not, so how can you then ask for a best practise on 'which operator should I use for doing math?'?

Comment: @Theo, but I did and my answer is still correct. You cannot promote a best practice without knowing for what this practice will be used for, and therefor I opted to point out that it is entirely dependent on the  code at hand and the choices made by the developer.

Comment: @Sean I could write an answer that explains the political situation in Sudan, while correct in itself it would still not answer the question. He explicitly says that he's not after an answer such as yours, so -1 for not reading the question.

Comment: @Theo, seriously, are you of the opinion that the answer the OP seeks actually exist? The premise of my answer is that if the OP *understands* what he is doing, then there *is no need* for a *best practice* (even if one could be presented for this case).